# Anchor with metal 1/2 inch behind drywall

Tags: drywall, anchor

I have a loose curtain rod that looks like it was screwed into a wall right where a metal shield happened to be on the back of the drywall.  It’s been a little loose since we moved into the house and I finally got around to fixing it. Looks like someone cut a plastic drywall anchor in half as an attempt to get the screw to stay in place. Was at least partially getting the job done, but obviously wasn’t a perfect hold.

Anyone have a good trick for getting a screw to hold when you can’t put a hole entirely through the drywall?  I was thinking either trying to glue the plastic anchor in place (with either putty or actual glue), or filling the hole with wood shavings and wood glue.

Comment: That's an odd place for a plate. Any idea what it's for?

Comment: @isherwood it's probably protecting something important behind it

Comment: Got any pics???

Answer (score 2):

If there is a metal plate behind that location, one that is protecting a cable or pipe, you *cannot* mount a curtain rod in that exact location.

For something light weight like a small photo frame, sure you could use glue or other tricks to stick things together but then you could just use Command Strips instead of screws for light weight.

But for a curtain: **You need to move the screw location.**

If the curtain is a valance or a very light weight curtain with no pull cords, you can probably just extend or contract the rod an inch or so to find hollow wall and use a drywall anchor (if you have drywall, or whatever is appropriate to your walls).

If the curtain will be touched by human hands, especially if it has cords or in some other way may be subject to rough treatment, you *must* find a way to mount to studs.  This might mean moving the rod up or down an inch (if you hit a metal plate in a stud).

If you *really* want to preserve the screw location there are methods using wood or metal pieces to straddle the area.   I recall, but cannot find, a similar question with an interesting approach to doing this with a hidden metal plate. But it's easier to just move the rod ... sideways or vertically, whatever works.